# Admin user can't update WP

Tags: wordpress, updates

I have a site running WP 4.1. The backend shows a bar saying "WordPress 4.7 is available! Please notify the site administrator."

I'm logged in as admin user, I double checked that.

Comment: Glad you got a solution - you can mark your own answer as the correct one :) I was curious though if the site was WP multi-site install?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that adding the following code to a new file (I called it role.php) and uploaded it to my wordpress root directory. Then I went to that page. www.yourblog.com/role.php

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');

$role = get_role('administrator');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($role);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I checked the array and a record for [update_core] with the value 1 was missing.

Then I added the following line after `$role = get_role('administrator')` line to add the `update_core` capability to the administrator.

$role->add_cap( 'update_core' );

I logged in as admin again and was able to do the update.

Don't forget to delete the file you've added afterwards.

Solution found on:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78419/admin-user-cant-update-wp

Thanks RRikesh (couldn't comment on that forum due to missing reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Check `wp-config.php` for:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);
```

And change it to:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',false);
```